# CSS same height as Parent

Tags: html, css, image, height

So I have an image that needs a `hover` effect;

**HTML**

```
 <div class="data">
    <img src="http://scontent-a-dfw.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpa1/t51.2885-15/e15/10809512_341410899374744_4010362_n.jpg"/>

    <div class="overlay"></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .data {
    width: 100px; 
    margin: auto; 
    padding: 5px; 
    height: auto; 
 }
 img {
    width: 100%; 
 }
 .overlay {
    width: 100%; 
    height: ___?; 
    background-color: blue; 
 }
```

As you can see, the height of `.data` is the same as the image. How can I make `.overlay` the same `height` of `.data`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the element is an overlay (as the name implies), i'd suggest relatively positioning the parent and then absolutely positioning the overlay *relative* to it:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrLnmLmr/)

```
.data {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.data .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
.data:hover .overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```